How to integrate the cited references from bib file into the source tex file?
I have a bib.bib file with content
@article{otto2001geometry,
  title={The geometry of dissipative evolution equations: the porous medium equation},
  author={Otto, Felix},
  year={2001},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}

and a tex file preprint.tex file content
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

The paper \cite{otto2001geometry} is seminal.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bib}

\end{document}

I have seen preprints (see, for instance, this and this) on arxiv.org where they contain only a single .tex file. This means the bibliography is also contained in that single file.
Could you explain how to combine preprint.tex and the cited references from bib.bib into a single .tex file?

Replace \bibliographystyle{unsrt}\bibliography{bib} by the contents of preprint.bbl.

replace \bibliographystyle{unsrt} \bibliography{bib} by the contents of preprint.bbl

@daleif ooh excellent suggestion:-)

@DavidCarlisledang good timing

Of course, you can handcode your references into the .tex file using bibitem. But keeping a separate .bib file will be easier to manage. If required, you compile your project using bibtex once and put the contents of the generated .bbl file into your .tex file as suggested in the comments.
Step 1. Compile once: pdflatex preprint.tex
Step 2. Run bibtex: bibtex preprint.tex
Step 3. Copy everything from preprint.bbl into preprint.tex by replacing \bibliographystyle{unsrt}\bibliography{bib}
Step 4. Compile twice: pdflatex preprint.tex and pdflatex preprint.tex
You can read more here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex
